# Unable to load model inside Controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For some reason my model is not loading properly (i think), or at least I can not access its methods.

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }
    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function login() {
        if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
        }
        if(isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = $_POST['password'];
        }
        // tried loading module here as well with no success
        $data = array('username'=>$username, 'password'=>$password);        
        $this->model->validateUser($data);
    }
}
```

Model

```
class User extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function validateUser($data)  {
        var_dump($data[0]." ".$data[1]);
    }
}
```

This is what it returns me `Call to a member function validateUser() on a non-object` I do not really see what and where is something wrong ? perhaps 2nd pair of eyes can help :) I am using CI 3+.

Comment: Why do you try to use $this->model-> when you are loading 'user'?

Comment: @Svetlio oh god... yes :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice for CI is to setup your Models with suffix (rename and the file)..

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
```

after that in your controller..

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$this->user_model->dosomething();
```

Comment: correct answer and handy tip ;) will accept after cooldown. Thank you